# What is the difference between PAGEIOLATCH_* and IO_COMPLETION?

Tags: sql-server, storage, wait-types, data-pages

according to [this](https://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2011/03/sql-server-io_completion-and-how-to-reduce-it.html) blog:

SQL Server Books online defines **IO_COMPLETION** as “Occurs while waiting for I/O operations to complete. *This wait type generally represents **non-data page I/Os**. **Data page I/O** completion waits appear as **PAGEIOLATCH_*** waits”*

What do non-data page IOs mean? or we can put the question in other way: What does actually “...waiting for I/O operations to complete“
mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PAGEIOLATCH_***

I am quoting from [Paul Randal's blog post](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/io-subsystem/knee-jerk-waits-pageiolatch-sh):

> SQL Server has two types of reads: logical I/Os and physical I/Os.
>   When the Access Methods portion of the Storage Engine needs to access
>   a page, it asks the Buffer Pool for a pointer to the page in memory
>   (called a logical I/O) and the Buffer Pool checks through its metadata
>   to see if that page is already in memory.
>
> If the page is in memory, the Buffer Pool gives the Access Methods the
>   pointer, and the I/O remains a logical I/O. If the page is not in
>   memory, the Buffer Pool issues a "real" I/O (called a physical I/O)
>   and the thread has to wait for it to complete – incurring a
>   **PAGEIOLATCH_XX wait**. Once the I/O completes and the pointer is
>   available, the thread is notified and can continue running.

**IO_COMPLETION**

Again quoting from a [webpage that belongs to sqlskills.com](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/io_completion/).

This wait type represents a variety of synchronous read and write operations in data files are not related to tables, plus reads from the transaction log.

**What do non-data page IOs mean?**

Few examples from [Paul Randal's article](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/causes-io_completion-write_completion-sql-server-wait-types/) will make it clear what `nod-data` page means.

- Reading log blocks from the transaction log (during any operation that causes the log to be read from disk – e.g. recovery)
- Reading allocation bitmaps from disk (e.g. GAM, SGAM, PFS pages) during many operations (e.g. recovery, DB startup, restore)
- Writing intermediate sort buffers to disk (these are called ‘Bobs’)
- Reading and writing merge results from/to disk during a merge join
- Reading and writing eager spools to disk
- Reading VLF headers from the transaction log

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/io_completion/    [(I think the detailed answer is on www.sqlskills.com)](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/io_completion/)